# while indexing getting SOLR error for newly added language in hybris : [doc=productCatalog/Online/product_code] unknown field 'spellcheck_de_DE''

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: ERROR: [doc=productCatalog/Online/productCode] unknown field 'spellcheck_de_DE'
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:681) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.SolrStandaloneSearchProvider$ClusterSolrClient.request(SolrStandaloneSearchProvider.java:503) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.CachedSolrClient.request(CachedSolrClient.java:64) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71) ~[solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3 e001c2221812a0ba9e9378855040ce72f93eced4 - jasongerlowski - 2020-10-03 18:12:06]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.SolrServerExporter.exportToUpdateIndex(SolrServerExporter.java:83) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.indexItems(DefaultIndexer.java:213) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.executeIndexerOperation(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:245) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.execute(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:210) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.doRun(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:195) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.run(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:151) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]

Config in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml seems to be correct but still facing this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share solrconfig.xml and schema.xml?

Comment: You can follow the steps described in this article to configure a new language for Solr :https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mapping-new-language-solr-abhishake-jain/

Answer (score 0):

For cloud version if you are running solr seperately (not in embeded mode) for your local machine, then you have to make changes in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files of that solr instance folder.